# Date problem (Error : 'from' must be of length 1)

Tags: r, date

This is the data that I have:

```
   `Fiscal Year` SiteState county     StartDate  EndDate    `Site Type` `Count of Site` `Sum of GallonsAppli~ ndays    id
 1 FY 18         IA        Butler     2017-11-21 2017-11-21 F                         3                554700 1 da~     1
 2 FY 18         IA        Cerro Gor~ 2017-10-18 2017-10-19 F                         1               1124085 2 da~     2
 3 FY 18         IA        Cerro Gor~ 2017-10-19 2017-10-19 F                         1                478240 1 da~     3
 4 FY 18         IA        Cerro Gor~ 2017-10-20 2017-10-20 F                         1                201306 1 da~     4
 5 FY 18         IA        Cerro Gor~ 2017-10-20 2017-10-21 F                         1                973760 2 da~     5
 6 FY 18         IA        Cerro Gor~ 2017-10-20 2017-10-23 F                         1                784743 4 da~     6
 7 FY 18         IA        Cerro Gor~ 2017-10-26 2017-10-26 F                         1                246462 1 da~     7
 8 FY 18         IA        Cerro Gor~ 2017-10-27 2017-10-29 F                         1                561808 3 da~     8
 9 FY 18         IA        Cerro Gor~ 2017-10-30 2017-10-30 F                         1                519946 1 da~     9
10 FY 18         IA        Cerro Gor~ 2017-11-02 2017-11-02 F                         2                816240 1 da~    10
11 FY 18         IA        Cerro Gor~ 2017-11-03 2017-11-08 F                         1               1260160 6 da~    11
12 FY 18         IA        Cerro Gor~ 2017-11-04 2017-11-04 F                         2                757145 1 da~    12
13 FY 18         IA        Cerro Gor~ 2017-11-05 2017-11-05 F                         3               1022532 1 da~    13
14 FY 18         IA        Cerro Gor~ 2017-11-06 2017-11-06 F                         1                565500 1 da~    14
15 FY 18         IA        Cerro Gor~ 2017-11-06 2017-11-07 F                         1                682500 2 da~    15
16 FY 18         IA        Cerro Gor~ 2017-11-07 2017-11-07 F                         3                905442 1 da~    16
17 FY 18         IA        Cerro Gor~ 2017-11-08 2017-11-08 F                         1                128880 1 da~    17
18 FY 18         IA        Cerro Gor~ 2017-11-09 2017-11-09 F                         2                509776 1 da~    18
19 FY 18         IA        Cerro Gor~ 2017-11-10 2017-11-11 F                         1                730916 2 da~    19
20 FY 18         IA        Cerro Gor~ 2017-11-12 2017-11-12 F                         1                440577 1 da~    20
```

I am trying to create a new data frame with all the fields except the dates. I want to create a new field date that will expand the dates if needed beteen the start date and the end date.

I have tried several ways but I always end getting and Error : 'from' must be of length 1

For example, if I try the simplest way to go,

```
dates <- seq( from = as.Date(data_clean$StartDate), to = as.Date(data_clean$EndDate), by = 1)
```

gives me:

> Error in seq.Date(from = as.Date(data_clean$StartDate), to = as.Date(data_clean$EndDate), : 'from' must be of length 1

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including example data in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(data_clean)`. We cannot copy/paste data from images.

Comment: The error tells you the problem. "'from' must be of length 1" means that it should contain one value (one date). The length of `data_clean$StartDate` is as many rows as are in `data_clean`.

Comment: How can I create a column with all the dates between StarDate and EndDate? Is there a way of going row by row? Thanks!

Comment: @CarlesVilalta It might be helpful for your example to show what your final, desired data frame should look like. You mentioned you want to "expand the dates", and "create a column with all the dates between StartDate and EndDate" - so for your example data above, what should that look like for the first 10-20 rows of your goal data frame, with this new column?